# Prove $F(z)=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-e^{-2\pi nt}e^{2\pi iz})$ is of growth order $2$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $t>0$ be given and fixed, and define $F(z)$ by
>   $$
> F(z)=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-e^{-2\pi nt}e^{2\pi iz}).
> $$
>   Show that $F(z)$ is of growth order $2$.

This is an exercise in Stein's Complex Analysis, chapter 5, exercise 4.

He gives a hint as follows:

[image]

I did know how to prove 
\begin{equation}
|F(z)|\leq Ae^{B |z|^2},\hspace{4cm}\text{(1)}
\end{equation}
but this is not sufficient to say that $F$ is of order $2$. So I want to prove that for any $\alpha<2$, and any constants $A,\,B$, there exists a $z_0$ such that the equation (1) fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by solving part (b) of that same exercise; namely, Stein and Shakarchi ask you to first show that the zeros are precisely at $z=-int+m$ for $n\geq 1, m\in \mathbb{Z}$, and then show that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{m^2+n^2t^2}=\infty.
\end{equation}
This implies $F$ is of order exactly $2$, for if it were of strictly smaller order, this sum would be convergent by Theorem 2.1 of that chapter.

Proving the zeros are as stated is straightforward, and for the last part, try the Integral Comparison test. You can show that for each fixed $n$, the inner sum is $\Omega(1/nt)$, so the series diverges.